# SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns thousand number

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, scope-identity

I have an insert query like the below. However, `scopeIdentity` does not return 42, it returns 1042.

This is the SQL Server table:

[image]

My code:

```
int masterId = 0;

using (SqlConnection cmd = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand conn = cmd.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.CommandText = "INSERT INTO[MasterReportData]([ReportName],[CaseList],[EmployeeId],[datetime]) VALUES(@reportName, @caseList, @employeeId, @datetime) SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

        conn.Parameters.Add("@reportName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reportName;
        conn.Parameters.Add("@caseList", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = caseList;
        conn.Parameters.Add("@employeeId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = employeeId;
        conn.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime;
        conn.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Open();
        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();

        masterId = Convert.ToInt32(conn.Parameters["@ID"].Value);
        cmd.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: missing semi-colon; ? why do you think it should return 42?  even if the last row was '41', rolled back inserts or deletes could have caused the counter to advance

Comment: So, if you look in the database, what value was actually inserted? Jumps of 1000 in identity columns is fairly common (since 2012, IIRC) and, anyway, if you care about the *actual numeric value*, I'd suggest you're using identity wrong.

Comment: Check the current value of your identity column on this table with: `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MasterReportData')` - what does it return?

Comment: @marc_s SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MasterReportData') returns 1042

Comment: So there you have it - the current value of your identity column **IS** in fact 1042 - the code worked **correctly** - there is no error

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

The description says:
*Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.*

In words: it Returns the last id and not the next to use. Therefore you can't use the INSERT command like that. What you can do is:

Configure your ID as auto-increment id. Then run the INSERT command and run SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() afterwards to find out which ID was used.